# Is it okay to miss one of vaccine (Pneumococcal conjugate vaccine) for infants?

Tags: vaccination, risks, infant, missed-dose

My local health center missed Pneumococcal conjugate(PCV) for my kid scheduled (as per the plan is given in the booklet) at two months age. Then they missed the same at four months age again due to unavailability. Finally, after they missed it at six months, I talked to the doctor and he gave a few excuses ... then he said it's not very important one. Missing it is not anything of concern.

Is he right?

Comment: Since this is essentially seeking a medical opinion, I'm going to migrate this to Health.SE.

Comment: What does "is it okay" mean? I think this question is too vague and opinion-oriented to be a fit on Health and should be closed.